# Torque and Equilibrium (Complex Question)

Tags: trigonometry, physics, mathematical-physics

> [![enter image description here][1]][1]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL03G.png

How much force $F$ (in terms of $G$) is needed to get through this sphere with the radius of $2r$, the weight of $G$, from the stair with the radius of $r$?

I had read the David Halliday's physics textbook, what I know are

$$\sum F_x = 0, \sum F_y = 0, \sum \tau= 0$$

Which tells us that the net force will be equal $0$ same as torque. However, I couldn't build the correct equation, let me show at least what I've written.

$$F - G + 2r + x = 0$$

I've gone truly wrong. Can you assist?

Regards!

Comment: If that downvote is for my attempt, I can show more about it.

Comment: Can anyone take a look? This question seems too complex and I don't know where to start. You can see the attached diagram If there's someone who knows physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontal and vertical equilibrium are satisfied by the reactions in the corner.

The torque equilibrium with respect to the corner of the stair is

$$\sum \tau= Fr-Mgd=0\implies F=\frac{Mgd}{r}$$

The problem reduces to find the horzontal distance $d$ between the corner of the stair and the center of the sphere that is

$$d=\sqrt{(2r)^2-r^2}=r\sqrt 3$$

Comment: Why did you find the $d$? no need to find it out. Also, what do you mean by $d$?

Comment: @Morata Why? since it depends upon r that is the given for the problem. Indeed we can conclude that $F=Mg\sqrt 3$.

Comment: @Morata Note that this is the Force F for which the sphere starts (slowly) to move up.

Comment: I still didn't get what you mean. This seems okay: $\sum \tau= Fr-Mgd=0\implies F=\frac{Mgd}{r}$ However, why we found the $d$?

Comment: @Morata Let me know what exactly is not clear to you.

Comment: Why did we find $d$? that's what I didn't get. Also, what do you mean by $d$?

Comment: @Morata We are writing **torque equilibrium** with respect to the up left corner of the stair it is given by the sum of the forces involved times the arm. For $ F$ the arm is $r$ and the torque $Fr$ is clockwise. For $Mg$ the arm is $d$ and the torque is counter-clockwise.

Comment: Do you have diagram? It'd be awesome if you can upload it.

Comment: @Morata Sorry I can't at the moment, I'll upload a diagram later!